# IIS url-rewrite port ignored

Tags: c#, redirect, iis, url-rewriting

I would like to use IIS url rewrite to send http request (all verbs) to an api that running on different port in localhost. In my web.config:

```
<rule name="ReverseProxyInboundRule2" stopProcessing="true">
    <match url="api/(.*)" />
    <conditions logicalGrouping="MatchAll">
        <add input="{SERVER_PORT}" pattern="^50276$" />
    </conditions>
    <action type="Rewrite" url="http://localhost:50327/api/{R:1}" logRewrittenUrl="true" />
</rule>
```

but IIS seems to ignore the action even if the matching is correct. It seems the problem is the port (changing from 50276 to 50327). Why?

Thanks

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/iis/extensions/url-rewrite-module/using-failed-request-tracing-to-trace-rewrite-rules

Comment: in which site you added this rule? you need to add this rule in the site which has 50276 port binding.